# Database query: get updates from friends

Tags: multi-table

EDIT: Got it!

```
SELECT `update`, `date` from updates, users_friends
WHERE updates.userID = users_friends.friendID
and users_friends.userID = "5"
and users_friends.status = "2"
```

I realised I was trying to call an update that didn't exist. In order to fix the problem I created a new update, this time written by user with id 6.

--

I'm building a social networking website. I wish to display a list of updates from friends. My database contains two tables to achieve this: updates and users_friends.

Here is my query:

SELECT 'update'
from updates
WHERE 'updates.userID' in
(SELECT 'friendID'
from users_friends
WHERE 'users_friends.userID' = $myID
and 'status' = 2);

(status value 2 means their friendship is approved)

--

### -- Table structure for table `updates`

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `updates` (
  `update` text NOT NULL,
  `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `userID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`date`,`userID`),
  KEY `fk_updates_users1` (`userID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--

### -- Table structure for table `users_friends`

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users_friends` (
  `userID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `friendID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `status` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`userID`,`friendID`),
  KEY `fk_users_has_friends_users1` (`userID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

The problem I'm having is that I always get an empty set. I have added a sample update to the updates table with userID = 5 and a sample row to the users_friends table where user 6 is friends with user 5 and myID = 6.

Is my logic correct? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why? I have a genuine problem here that I'm looking to fix.

Comment: Got it! 

    SELECT `update`, `date` from updates, users_friends
    WHERE updates.userID = users_friends.friendID
    and users_friends.userID = "5"
    and users_friends.status = "2"

I realised I was trying to call an update that didn't exist. In order to fix the problem I created a new update, this time written by user with id 6.

Comment: you are going to cause yourself no end of grief using reserved words such as UPDATE and DATE as field names. Can I suggest that at the early stage in your development you rename them. eg updateText and entryDate.  as small amount of rework now will much grief later

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT `update`, `date` from updates, users_friends
WHERE updates.userID = users_friends.friendID
and users_friends.userID = "5"
and users_friends.status = "2"
```

I realised I was trying to call an update that didn't exist. In order to fix the problem I created a new update, this time written by user with id 6.